# How UPDATE(column) function works in case of batch updates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

SQL Server triggers execute on batches instead of each row in the update transaction.

If 'N' rows of a table were updated in a single transaction, the UPDATE Trigger will execute on the 'N' rows together. (`UPDATE()`: [Link to MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16))

How does the trigger function `UPDATE()` work in such scenario, assuming the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sample](
    SampleId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Column1 VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Sample] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SampleId ASC)
);
```

Considering this update on the table:

```
UPDATE Sample SET Column1 = 'Example' WHERE SampleId <= 5;
```

And, if inside the update trigger for above table there is this condition:

```
IF UPDATE(Column1)
```

- Will the above condition evaluate to True if Column1 is updated in each of the 'N' updates, or will it evaluate to True if any one of the 'N' updates have an update on Column1?
- Or is there a way to use it on each update one by one?

Edit: 
If there are 2 different updates on the same table in a single transaction, will the Update trigger fire once for each Update statement, or once for all updates in that transaction?

Comment: can you give an example of an UPDATE statement that works across N rows but updates only a subset  of those rows Column1 values?

Comment: From your linked doc: "If a trigger applies to a column, the UPDATED value will return as true or 1, even if the column value remains unchanged.". So even if your proposed update only affected one row and that row's `Column1` value was *already* `Example`, `UPDATE` would still return true.

Comment: I think you might be expected the `update` function to tell you when the data changes - it doesn't do that.

Comment: *"f there are 2 different updates on the same table in a single transaction, will the Update trigger fire once for each Update statement, or once for all updates in that transaction?"* Surely this is something you can easily test and find out yourself, no? What did your tests reveal?

Comment: Every and each update statement executes the trigger separately. What are you fishing for *really*? Surely the question have some actual problem at hand

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) answers all your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the column is included in the `SET`clause of the `UPDATE` then `UPDATE()` returns true; it's as simple as that. `UPDATE()` considers the **statement** not the row *or* the data.

Take a simple statement like this:

```sql
UPDATE SomeTable
SET SomeColumn = 1
WHERE SomeColumn = 1
```

This would result in `UPDATE(SomeColumn)` being true; `SomeColumn` was included in the `SET` clause. `UPDATE(AnotherColumn)` would be false, as it wasn't included.

If there are multiple rows effected, or none, it doesn't matter.

As a full working example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                            SomeInt int,
                            SomeString varchar(10));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeInt,SomeString)
VALUES(1,'abc'),
      (2,'def'),
      (2,'ghi');
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trg_SomeTrigger ON dbo.SomeTable
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN

    IF UPDATE(SomeString)
        PRINT N'SomeString was updated';
END;
GO
--Prints statement, SomeString was updated.
--1 row is affected, though the value doesn't change.
UPDATE dbo.SomeTable
SET SomeString = 'abc'
WHERE SomeInt = 1;
GO
--Prints statement, SomeString was updated.
--2 rows are affected, the values do change.
UPDATE dbo.SomeTable
SET SomeString = '123'
WHERE SomeInt = 2;
GO
--Prints statement, SomeString was updated.
--0 rows are affected, no values change.
UPDATE dbo.SomeTable
SET SomeString = 'abc'
WHERE SomeInt = 3;
GO
--Doesn't Print statement, as SomeString wasn't updated.
--1 row is affected, but not SomeString.
UPDATE dbo.SomeTable
SET SomeInt = 3
WHERE SomeInt = 1;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
```

If you want to check if a row and column's value has *changed* you need to inspect the values in the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables. If you are on SQL Server 2022 then this is much easier with `IS DISTINCT FROM`. On older versions, if the column is `NULL`able you'll need to ensure you check for that too. For example:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trg_AnotherTrigger ON dbo.SomeTable
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM inserted i
                    JOIN deleted d ON i.ID = d.ID
               WHERE i.SomeString IS DISTINCT FROM d.SomeString)
        PRINT N'SomeString was updated and a value was changed';
END;
```

The above trigger would only `PRINT` for the second `UPDATE` statement, where values of `SomeString` where changed.
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QSmJs4yW)

Comment: Thank you! I missed the actual scenario I had in mind, could you please check the edit to the question?

Comment: That is a different question, @SubhankarNayak . You shouldn't really be changing a question *after* it's been answered.